# Is it possible for JTextPane to have columns and rows?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, tabular

I have `JTextPane` from Netbeans designer's section. I want to add columns and rows on it. However, there is no option for adding columns or row in the property window of `JTextPane`. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JTextPane` supports formatted documents.  One format it supports is HTML.  Therefore, it is possible to use an HTML `table` to provide tabular data - data in columns and rows.

---

Also consider using a [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html), which (of course) has inbuilt support for columns and rows.

Answer (score 4):

`JTextPane` is not meant to have "columns" and "rows": however you can alter its content through the NetBeans designer by editing its `text` property (*click on the* `...` *next to the* `text` *property in order to open a dialog where you can enter some multiline text for your JTextPane*).

Comment: _Thank you very much for you're help Unai Vivi again.

Answer (score 3):

You can add your custom tables like described here
http://java-sl.com/JEditorPaneTables.html

and

row/cols insert described here
http://java-sl.com/JEditorPaneTablesRowColumnInsert.html

Answer (score 1):

you can override JTextPane class methods and
add columns and rows to  JTextPane:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class TextPane extends JTextPane {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 712368129156703980L;

    private int rows, columns, rowHeight, columnWidth;

    public TextPane() {

        super();

        rows = 0;
        columns = 0;

    }

    public TextPane(StyledDocument doc) {

        super(doc);

        rows = 0;
        columns = 0;

    }

    public TextPane(int rows, int columns) {

        super();

        this.rows = rows;
        this.columns = columns;

    }

    public TextPane(StyledDocument doc, int rows, int columns) {

        super(doc);

        this.rows = rows;
        this.columns = columns;

    }

    public int getRows() {
        return rows;

    }

    public void setRows(int rows) {

        if (rows < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("rows less than zero.");

        if (rows != this.rows) {

            this.rows = rows;
            revalidate();

        }

    }

    public int getRowHeight() {

        if (rowHeight == 0) {

            FontMetrics metrics = getFontMetrics(getFont());
            rowHeight = metrics.getHeight();

        }

        return rowHeight;

    }

    public int getColumns() {
        return columns;

    }

    public void setColumns(int columns) {

        if (columns < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("columns less than zero.");

        if (columns != this.columns) {

            this.columns = columns;
            revalidate();

        }

    }

    public int getColumnWidth() {

        if (columnWidth == 0) {

            FontMetrics metrics = getFontMetrics(getFont());
            columnWidth = metrics.charWidth('m');

        }

        return columnWidth;
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {

        Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize();

        d = (d == null) ? new Dimension(400, 400) : d;
        Insets insets = getInsets();

        if (columns != 0)
            d.width = Math.max(d.width, columns * columnWidth + insets.left + insets.right);

        if (rows != 0)
            d.height = Math.max(d.height, rows * rowHeight + insets.top + insets.bottom);

        return d;

    }

    protected String paramString() {

        return super.paramString() + ",columns" + columns + ",columnWidth" + columnWidth + ",rows" + rows
                + ",,rowsHeight" + rowHeight;

    }

    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {

        Dimension size = super.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize();
        size = (size == null) ? new Dimension(400, 400) : size;
        Insets insets = getInsets();

        size.width = (columns == 0) ? size.width : columns * getColumnWidth() + insets.left + insets.right;

        size.height = (rows == 0) ? size.height : rows * getRowHeight() + insets.top + insets.bottom;

        return size;


    }

     public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {

            switch (orientation) {

            case SwingConstants.VERTICAL:
                return getRowHeight();

            case SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL:
                return getColumnWidth();

            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid orientation: " + orientation);

            }

        }



}
```