# JTextPane - dynamic word wrap

Tags: java, swing, word-wrap, jtextpane

I tried to use `jTextPane1.setText("xxx xxxx xxx xxxxx xx xxx xxxx xxx etc...");` but `JTextPane` does not word wrap it at all showing all the text in one line only instead.
It would be interesting to support word wrap on `jTextPane1` resized too...

So my question is... 
how to make `JTextPane` support word wrap?

Comment: I don't use JTextArea because I need dynamic height support.

Comment: I am not pretty sure how to make JTextArea support rows++ :(

Comment: @user592704 I'm confused so what is your question about JTextArea's or JTextPanes, because my answer has both, however now you say "not pretty sure how to make JTextArea support rows++"??

Comment: My question is about JTextPane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `JTextArea` and call `setWrapStyleWord(true);` on its instance this should do what you need.

EDIT:

If you need to use a `JTextPane` as a requirement(which you said you do), then have a look at a similar question that I found which answer should be of help: [How is word-wrapping implemented in JTextPane, and how do I make it wrap a string without spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036543/how-is-word-wrapping-implemented-in-jtextpane-and-how-do-i-make-it-wrap-a-strin)

Comment: Emm... the issue is about JEditorPane not the JTextPane :( You mean using JEditorPane instead?

Comment: No the first link does discuss using JTextPanes, however, yes a JEditor could do that too as seen in the 2nd link of the answer

Comment: @user592704, This link too might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980792/is-it-possible-for-jtextpane-to-have-columns-and-rows

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the solution from David Kroukamp was very helpful. I changed it to JTextArea and set the following properties, as described in this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html):

```
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

Comment: -1. Why does this have any upvotes? this doesn't answer the question at all. The answer doesn't even say that it is for a `JTextArea` and not a `JTextPane`. Not that it matters because, again, the question has nothing to do with a `JTextArea` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a JTextArea instead of a Pane?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/

> public void setWrapStyleWord(boolean word)

Sets the style of wrapping used if the text area is wrapping lines. If set to true the lines will be wrapped at word boundaries (whitespace) if they are too long to fit within the allocated width. If set to false, the lines will be wrapped at character boundaries. By default this property is false. Parameters: word - indicates if word boundaries should be used for line wrapping See Also: getWrapStyleWord()

Comment: because I am interested in text pane dynamic rows++ support. Not the scrolling